Tooltip is appearing on wrong element in Chome
I am facing an issue related to the tooltip on Chrome for this code:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img style="width: min(100%, 800px);" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c8/Altja_j%C3%B5gi_Lahemaal.jpg" alt="Nature Image">
    <div>
        <a href="https://google.com">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 48 48">
                <title>Google Logo</title>
                <path fill="#fbc02d" d="M43.611,20.083H42V20H24v8h11.303c-1.649,4.657-6.08,8-11.303,8c-6.627,0-12-5.373-12-12   s5.373-12,12-12c3.059,0,5.842,1.154,7.961,3.039l5.657-5.657C34.046,6.053,29.268,4,24,4C12.955,4,4,12.955,4,24s8.955,20,20,20    s20-8.955,20-20C44,22.659,43.862,21.35,43.611,20.083z"></path><path fill="#e53935" d="M6.306,14.691l6.571,4.819C14.655,15.108,18.961,12,24,12c3.059,0,5.842,1.154,7.961,3.039   l5.657-5.657C34.046,6.053,29.268,4,24,4C16.318,4,9.656,8.337,6.306,14.691z"></path><path fill="#4caf50" d="M24,44c5.166,0,9.86-1.977,13.409-5.192l-6.19-5.238C29.211,35.091,26.715,36,24,36 c-5.202,0-9.619-3.317-11.283-7.946l-6.522,5.025C9.505,39.556,16.227,44,24,44z"></path><path fill="#1565c0" d="M43.611,20.083L43.595,20L42,20H24v8h11.303c-0.792,2.237-2.231,4.166-4.087,5.571   c0.001-0.001,0.002-0.001,0.003-0.002l6.19,5.238C36.971,39.205,44,34,44,24C44,22.659,43.862,21.35,43.611,20.083z"></path>
            </svg>
        </a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>



Steps to re-produce the bug:

Use the above code and open the site in Chrome
Don't use full screen
Open the link in a new window
Close that window
Immediately put the cursor over the image
Tooltip should be visible after 1-5 seconds

Here is a demo of this issue.
This tooltip has the text Google Logo, which is incorrect. I used the Google logo in the title tag of svg only, so ideally, this tooltip should only be visible when hovering over that svg. But is visible in the image.
Does anyone know what the problem is with it, or is it Chrome's bug?
I tried with another browser, but not able to reproduce it. It seems like Chrome's bug, but I'm not sure.

Can you write your code in StackOverflow Snippet syntax With the [<>] button in the editor. It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you.

You should report Chrome bugs to Chrome's bugtracker

Thanks @Danny'365CSI'Engelman

@RobertLongson Sure, but I want to ensure that it's not an implementation bug
